# How to make a wave warp effect in shader?

Tags: opengl, 2d, glsl, textures, shader

I want to make a wave warp effect like this:

[image: wave1]

But I can only create the normal sine wave.

Here is my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;

vec2 SineWave( vec2 p ){
    float pi = 3.14159;
    float A = 0.15;
    float w = 10.0 * pi;
    float t = 30.0*pi/180.0;
    float y = sin( w*p.x + t) * A; 
    return vec2(p.x, p.y+y);　
}
void main(){
    vec2 p = v_texCoord; 
    vec2 uv = SineWave( p ); 
    vec4 tcolor = texture2D(s_baseMap, uv); 
    gl_FragColor = tcolor; 
}
```

and result is:

[image: wave2]

So the question is how to warp the wave on a specific direction?

thanks.

here is the origin texture:
[image: origin texture]

---

update:
I distort x axis when compute y, but the result seems not right.

```
float x = p.x + p.y*tan( -0.5); 
float y = sin( w*x + t) * A;
return vec2(p.x, p.y+y);
```

[image: distort x axis]

Comment: 1. you should add also the undistorted input texture for testing. 2. you need to distort also `x` axis you are computing `y = sin( w*p.x + t) * A; ` so try to distort also the `x`  like `x = sin( w*p.y + t) * A; ` and may be play a bit with constants (having separate constants for `x` and for `y`).

Comment: thanks for reply, I try to distort x asix, and apply v_texCoord.y as the factor. but the result seems not right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK I tried to recreate your effect so I used this as texture:

[image: texture]

I took your image and resize it to `512x512` so it is power of 2 fill the border with black. As you do not share Vertex shader I created my own. The **GL** is rendering single quad `<-1,+1>` without texture coordinates or matrices only `glVertex2f()` with single **2D** texture binded to unit `0`. I slightly rewrite your fragment to match the output. Also I added `tx,ty` uniforms to easily animate the effect with mouse position `<0,1>` Here are the shaders first vertex:

```
// Vertex
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main()
    {
    v_texCoord=gl_Vertex.xy;
    gl_Position=gl_Vertex;
    }
```

And then fragment:

```
// Fragment
varying vec2 v_texCoord;        // holds the Vertex position <-1,+1> !!!
uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;    // used texture unit
uniform float tx,ty;            // x,y waves phase

vec2 SineWave( vec2 p )
    {
    // convert Vertex position <-1,+1> to texture coordinate <0,1> and some shrinking so the effect dont overlap screen
    p.x=( 0.55*p.x)+0.5;
    p.y=(-0.55*p.y)+0.5;
    // wave distortion
    float x = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x + 6.28*tx) * 0.05;
    float y = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x + 6.28*ty) * 0.05;
    return vec2(p.x+x, p.y+y);
    }

void main()
    {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_baseMap,SineWave(v_texCoord));
    }
```

This is output for `tx=0.3477,ty=0.7812` which visually more or less matches your example:

[image: output]

As you can see I added few terms into the sin waves so it got also skew distortion.

If you have the `v_texCoord` already in range `<0,1>` then ignore the

```
    p.x=( 0.55*p.x)+0.5;
    p.y=(-0.55*p.y)+0.5;
```

or rewrite it to (so the shrink and coefficients stay as should)

```
    p.x=(1.1*p.x)-0.05;
    p.y=(1.1*p.y)-0.05;
```

If you use different texture (not mine) then you need to rescale all the coefficients.

**[edit1] coefficients meaning**

first I started with yours:

```
float x = sin( 10.0*p.y) * 0.15;
float y = sin( 10.0*p.x) * 0.15;
```

The `0.15` is wave amplitude which seems to be too big so I lower it to `0.05`. Then `10.0` is frequency the bigger the number the more waves along axis will be. By pure trial&error I determine they should be `30.0` for y axis and `25.0` for x axis so the number of waves matches your desired output.

```
float x = sin( 25.0*p.y) * 0.05;
float y = sin( 30.0*p.x) * 0.05;
```

After this I spotted that the waves should be a bit skewed so I add dependency on the other axis too after some tweaking found out this equation:

```
float x = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x) * 0.05;
float y = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x) * 0.05;
```

where both coefficients are the same in between axises (weird but working I was expecting I would need to have different coefficients between axises). After this is just a matter of finding the correct phase for each axis so I add phase shift controlled by mouse position `(tx,ty) <0.0,1.0>` so I got the final:

```
float x = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x + 6.28*tx) * 0.05;
float y = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x + 6.28*ty) * 0.05;
```

Then I play with mouse (printing its position) until I got close enough to match your desired output which was when `tx=0.3477,ty=0.7812` so you can hard-code

```
float x = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x + 6.28*0.3477) * 0.05;
float y = sin( 25.0*p.y + 30.0*p.x + 6.28*0.7812) * 0.05;
```

Comment: it looks pretty good! can you explain some math about the algorithm? why use these coeffients

Comment: thanks for the help :)  by the way, what framework do you use, can you control the coefficients in real time?

Comment: @thrillerist I do not use any frameworks. I use C++ and VCL environment. And yes I can control any uniforms on runtime if I want (it is just matter of few lines of code to control them either by mouse or keyboard or GUI) but in this case I controlled only the `tx,ty` this way. (The time I would spend on learning some framework is usually bigger then to code desired functionality on my own and using frameworks in my line of work brings only problems in the future like discontinuity,compatibility issues...)