# Stationary and progressive wave shader in Godot, which makes bullet look like a electromagnetic wave

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, godot

I am having a Bullet scene, with Sprite node which looks like a short laser beam. But when Player shoots, bullet looks boring, so I decided to add a shader material to it. I wanted it to look like a stationary wave, so when it moves it looks progressive. I looked at this question: "[How to make a wave warp effect in shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174431/how-to-make-a-wave-warp-effect-in-shader)" But that was not what I would like to have, because the oscillation is not vertical.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has a limitation. It will work only if the bullet sprite canvas leaves enough space for oscillation (i.e. bullet doesn't take entire canvas)

```c
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform float amplitude;
uniform float inv_wavelength; // wavelength^(-1), where the wavelength is the width of the sprite
uniform float frequency;

const float TWO_PI = 6.2832;

vec2 sine_wave( vec2 p, float time ) {
    float y = sin(p.x * inv_wavelength * TWO_PI) * amplitude * sin(frequency * TWO_PI * time);
    return vec2(p.x, p.y + y);
}

void fragment() {
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, sine_wave(UV, TIME));
}
```

I let `amplitude` equal 0.2, as at values greater than 0.5 oscillation is not fully visible.`inv_wavelength` equals 4.0 means that wavelength will be 1/4 of the sprite width. I am not confident about the math of it. But my understanding is that the first `sin()` is responsible for original y-displacement which depends on the horizontal distance from the left edge of the sprite `p.x` (`UV.x`). The second `sin()` function displaces it over time. The higher the `frequency` the higher the oscillation speed. Using `TIME` inside the custom function returned an error, so I passed it as a parameter.

P.S. I observed, that wave can become progressive if a multiple of global time is added to the first `sin()`, the larger multiplier will make the wave move faster.

```c
float y = sin(p.x * inv_wavelength * TWO_PI + 5.0 * time) * amplitude * sin(frequency * TWO_PI * time);
```