# Guidance on how to create a distorted shader effect?

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, react-three-fiber, vertex-shader

I'm new to shaders specifically GLSL but am familar with concepts in generative art used in touch designer and javascript. I'm trying to create a shader material in react3 fiber, I want to create a simple distortion on my 3d object:

Before -
[image: 3D GLTF]

After -
[image: DISTORTED]

I'm not show what and how i should be going about this would i be writing a vertex shader or fragment shader? How i approach this should it be math created noise or an image based noise displacement? I will be animating the displacement later so would need to be a uniform factor/value.

Just need some starter concepts to point me towards :)

Comment: Not familiar with react 3 fiber, but to do the above effect with animation of the bubbly looking area, I would not be modifying the basic vertex shader. Looks like it must already be passing normals to the fragment shader in the before version. I would generate noise using a function so you can rapidly iterate and tweak the values to find the effect you want. Use the screen X and Y and elapsed time as the inputs to a 2D noise function, and then scale the noise output using dot product of the model's normal with the camera direction. Then do some kind of clamping on that to get the final color.

Comment: see this [How to make a wave warp effect in shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176935/2521214) for some inspiration its not the same but very similar maybe adding some cuting plane and noise to waves amplitude would create holes like you want